# Running Time Calculate

Tags: java, c++, c, windows

How to  calculate running time of the particular process running in the Windows Task Manager using java code or C/C++ code.

i.e. How much time this process is running after the Windows Logon.

Comment: Is it this http://www.manictime.com/ you want? Also you can use powershell as follows.  Measure-Command {start-process java -argumentlist "whateverargumentisneeded" -wait}

Comment: There is a column **cpu time** in the task manager. Use **view -> select columns** to make it display.

Answer (score 1):

Use GetProcessTimes windows api to get the information about a process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is any use to you, but I was calculating CPU time for a project in C:

```
clock_t start = clock() ;
clock_t end = clock() ;
    double CPU_Time = ( end-start ) / ( double )CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf( "string %f\n", CPU_Time );
```

Hope it helps!